# jQuery stepper doesn't trigger the change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, haml

I want to toggle the visibility of the submit button on change of input fields.

Since the HTML5 input `type="number"` is not supported in firefox, I use the [stepper jQuery plugin](https://github.com/xFlatlinex/Numeric-Stepper).

The submit button is initially hidden and when changes are made to any form field including the stepper, the submit button should be displayed but when I change numbers, the change event is not triggered.

In Chrome the default event for a `type="number"` field works fine

**HAML**

```
.form-actions.hide{
     :style => 'border-top: none; 
     border-bottom: solid 1px; 
     border-bottom-color: #08C;'
}
%button#submit{
     :type => "submit", 
     :class => 'btn btn-primary', 
     :style => 'margin-top: -28px;'
} Submit
```

**JavaScript**

```
if(BrowserDetect.browser == "Firefox"){
   $('#count').stepper();
}
$('#manage form input[type!=submit], select').change(function() {
   $('#manage form .form-actions').show();
});
```

Comment: Show code and link to plugin or make a jsfiddle.net. For example this one has an onstep https://github.com/xFlatlinex/Numeric-Stepper

Comment: haml code for top alignment of button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not optimal to detect browser. Instead detect support for number

```
function hasNumber() {
  var inp = document.createElement("input");
  inp.setAttribute("type", "number");
  return inp.type !== "text";
}
```

Then according to the documentation you need

```
function changeField() {
  $('#manage form .form-actions').show();
}
$(function() {
  if (!hasNumber()) {
  $('#manage form input[type!=submit], select').change(changeField);
    $('#count').stepper({
      onStep: function( val, up ) {
        changeField();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: In IE instead of upward and downward triangle symbols, there are two & symbols in stepper how to fix it?

Comment: Did you set the charset to UTF8? Does THIS: ▴ show a triangle?